# iphone code to calculate few transmission parameters like CIR, FER, RSSI etc

Tags: iphone, networking, core-telephony, transmission

Looking for a sample code or tutorial to fetch few transmission parameters like

```
1. RXlevel (Signal Strength)
2. RXQual (Bit Error Rate)
3. C/I (carrier to interference)
4. FER (Frame erase rate
6. towers location.
7. Radio access technology
8. mobile country code
9. mobile network code
10. location code area 
11. CELL ID
12. absolute RF channel number
13. base station identity code
13. RSSI
14. C1 hand-over parametr
15. CELLS information for example:
    a. absolute RF channel number.
    b. base station identity code
    c. RSSI
```

I noticed a application Signal which must be using something similar, but since it only works on Jailbroken devices I understand it is using private API. Can anyone recommend which private framework can provide this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at CoreTelephony, but it only gives a few things (mobile country code, mobile network code) [Apple Docs for CoreTelephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) see CTCarrier class.

Comment: David thanks for information, is there a way to get other parameters like RxLevel, RxQual etc? Any public API / Framework if not Apple's